# All props are given type 'never'

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I've started SvelteKit skeleton project for my personal website. However, when trying to use svelte in conjunction with typescript I get `Type '<some prop type>' is not assignable to type 'never'. (ts 2322)` on all props for any component I make (reported through `npx svelte-check` as well). I'm new to svelte so I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.

The project uses SvelteKit, TailwindCSS, and the `svelte-icons` library for icons.

`src/routes/+page.svelte`

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Navbar, {type NavItem} from "$lib/components/Navbar.svelte";

import Linkage, {type Link} from "$lib/components/Linkage.svelte";

const navlinks: NavItem[] = [
    { text: "About me", link: "#about" },
    { text: "Projects", link: "#projects" },
    { text: "CV", link: "#cv" },
    { text: "Links", link: "#links" }
];

const outlinks: Link[] = [
    {icon: null}
];
</script>

<!-- items: Type 'NavItem[]' is not assignable to type 'never'. (ts 2322)-->
<Navbar items={navlinks}/>

<!-- links: Type 'Link[]' is not assignable to type 'never'. (ts 2322) -->
<Linkage links={outlinks}/>
```

`src/lib/components/Navbar.svelte`

```html
<script context="module" lang="ts">
import MdMenu from 'svelte-icons/md/MdMenu.svelte';

export interface NavItem {
    text: string;
    link: string;
};

export let items: NavItem[] = [{
    text: "Example",
    link: "https://www.example.com/"
}];
</script>

<div class="absolute flex transition-transform ease-in-out duration-300 translate-x-0 hover:-translate-x-0 bg-slate-500 transition-colors text-white">
    <div class="p-1">
        <div class="w-6 h-6">
            <MdMenu/>
        </div>
    </div>

    {#each items as item}
        <div class="p-1 hover:text-orange-500 hover:bg-slate-200">
            <a href="{item.link}"> {item.text} </a>
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

`src/lib/components/Linkage.svelte`

```
<script context="module" lang="ts">
export interface Link {
    icon: null | string | unknown;
}

export let links: Link[] = [];
</script>
```

To be clear about the question: What is causing the issue and how is it solved?

Let me know if any more information is needed, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`context="module"`](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-context-module) on the scripts specifies *static* code for the component, not its instances. Hence the `export let ...` statements do not define properties at all.

Simply remove `context="module"`/move instance code like properties to a separate script without it. (Personally, I extract interfaces that need to be exported to separate files, so having any `context="module"` scripts is usually not necessary.)